# Remove all but the three word from a sentence and add three dots after that three sentence using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to Remove all but the three word from a sentence and add three dots after that three sentence using jquery. example if the sentence is " We evaluate our borrowers on a periodic basis. See our evaluations " so in that remove "*borrowers on a periodic basis. See our evaluations See our evaluations*" and i want to show like this "**We evaluate our...**" i tried here is [code](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/Rpq7b/1/)

Comment: Have you tried `text-overflow: ellipsis;` as an alternative?

Comment: @Josh Davenport hi i tried text-overflow:ellipsis; it's not working here is my example http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/Rpq7b/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Javascript only supports lookaheads not lookbehinds...but yes there are work arounds**

This will work for you...

```
var str="How are you doing today?";

regexp = new RegExp('(' + str.match(/(\w+\s){2}\w+/g)+ ')?.*'); //fetches first 3 words and makes regural expression to lookbehind this positively
var output = str.replace(regexp, function($0, $1){     //mimicks positive lookbehind
    return $1 ? $1 + '...' : $0;
});

document.writeln(output );
```

**UPDATE - this worked for the "How are you.." only....so use the below one**

Here is a very good tutorial to mimicking negative and positive lookbehinds in javascript as it does not support it...

Javascript only supports lookaheads

http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript

**UPDATE - this works fine for anything like in your example**

```
var str="We evaluate our borrowers on a periodic basis. See our evaluationsWe evaluate our borrowers on a periodic basis. See our evaluationsWe evaluate our borrowers on a periodic basis. See our evaluations";

var first_three = str.match(/(\w+\s){2}\w+/);

regexp = new RegExp('(' + first_three[0] + ')?.*'); //fetches first 3 words and makes regural expression to lookbehind this positively
var output = str.replace(regexp, function($0, $1){     //mimicks positive lookbehind
    return $1 ? $1 + '...' : $0;
});

document.writeln(output);​
```

and a running jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Rpq7b/2/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the css rule `text-overflow` to achieve this. Here's a class you can use to achieve the result you want:

```
.prevent-overflow { 
    white-space: nowrap; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis
}​
```

Here's a break down of what this does: `white-space: nowrap;` stops the text form wrapping onto a new line when the edge of the element is reached. `overflow:hidden` tells the text to never appear outside the bounds of the element and `text-overflow: ellipsis` tells the browser to place `...` at the end of the text whenever any gets cut off (see [text-overflow @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-overflow)).

Apply it to an element with dimensions that will cut off the text contained within it.

I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshdavenport/hem6a/1/) to demonstrate it's use.

**Note:** The [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/Rpq7b/) contained a div at the end of the element (`<div style="clear:both"></div>`) which stops the ellipsis from working (see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshdavenport/hem6a/)), I suggest you apply `clear:both;` to the entire div instead, or find another way to achieve whatever the purpose of that `<div>` was.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following function:

```
function myfunction(val)
{
    temp = val.split(' ');

    if(val.length >= 2)
    {
         val = temp[0] + ' ' + temp[1] + ' ' + temp[2] + ' ..';
    }

    return val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should work

```
 var yourText = " We evaluate our borrowers on a periodic basis", 

 result = yourText.replace(/^(.{15}[^\s]*).*/, "$1");

 alert(result);
```

Note: Play around with the `15` in the code to any suitable number of yours

To get the the ellipsis stuff: you can add `result` + `"&hellip;"`